# Google Sheets - use mulitple IF statements in one cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to summarize three if statements in one cell but only getting a "formula parse error"

here are my statements:

```
IF(E_CONTRACT = "SENT"; TODAY()+7; "")
IF(E_CONTRACT = "SIGNED"; "Reminder disabled"; "")
IF(E_CONTRACT = "NOT SENT"; "-"; "")
```

I tried

```
IF(E_CONTRACT = "SENT"; TODAY()+7; ""), 
IF(E_CONTRACT = "SIGNED"; "Reminder disabled"; ""), 
IF(E_CONTRACT = "NOT SENT"; "-"; "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in place of E-Contract you are pointing to a cell with a value in it, here is the correct format:

```
=IF(E_CONTRACT = "SENT", TODAY()+7, IF(E_CONTRACT = "SIGNED", "Reminder disabled", IF(E_CONTRACT = "NOT SENT", "-", "")))
```

Comment: yes, i'm pointing to E_CONTRACT (dropdown) where 3 possible states are possible but your format doesn't work